# Is CGContextFillRects faster than CGContextFillRect?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some code in my iOS application where I'm drawing multiple blocks using multiple calls to `CGContextFillRect`. Not surprisingly from what I've heard, the drawing call is using up most of the time in my application.

With a bit of work, I could probably refactor this to make a smaller number of calls to `CGContextFillRects`, but I'm curious to know if doing so will give me any performance improvement, or if this is simply a convenience method that doesn't result in any other benefits.

Anybody know before I go through the trouble of refactoring my code?